# Opening a PDF from file from a shared drive as a link in html

Tags: html, asp.net

We build our local corporate site, and it has a lot of links to PDF files, located in our shared drive. Both are accessed with VPN, so when you can access the website, you can access the shared drive.

It would be so nice to be able to open these PDF links with one click, but I'm struggling to find a way to do that. I know that these are security restriction not to be able to do that, so I'm looking for a way to overcome this. For example I was able to find a way to do that for office applications with URI scheme (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn906146.aspx)

- Our web is HTTPS. I think this is the reason why normal links do not work (neither Q:\...pdf nor file:\Q:\...pdf). Chrome displays "Not allowed to load local resource". IFrames with the link also do not work. **Update: Nothing to do with HTTPS. Doesn't work for HTTP as well. Not sure why people say it works for them?**
- Writing an action to load pdf and return it as a response is a very good solution, but due to security issues we cannot use it. Each PDF file should be opened by the local user, so our IT could control the access.
- The target client machine can have different PDF viewers installed, we do not use a single one corporate-wise.

My best hope for finding a URI scheme for pdf, that is general to pdf viewer (so link 'acrobatreader:q:\...pdf' doesn't work for us), but I couldn't find any. Does that exist at all? And are there any other clever ways of doing this?

Comment: Can you show us the code that is loading your files? Your error message looks like you are trying to convince chrome to load files from the clients local Q folder, instead of using `Server.MapPath(../path/to/documents/)`

Comment: @Marco That's what I am trying to do. Q drive is a client folder accessible for everybody. Server actually doesn't have an access to Q drive due to Q drive having different file permissions for every user in our Active Directory

Comment: @Marco Imagine a server being a web site with the details of our projects, and Q drive a file storage for different documentation for each project. People got used to have a Q drive, so we are not changing it, but we are adding a web site to help managing the projects. Unfortunately web site is not designed to control project permissions (everybody can see all the projects), but we have a permission control on Q drive, so web site cannot have a direct access to Q drive, but rather it should delegate the links to the user who wants to open the file

Comment: That is ... adventurous. Ok 1. Do not use mappings. Use Host names. Mappings can change. 2. Let the web application access all the files. If a user wants to read a pdf, check if his domain user has permissions for it. If so serve the file. if not - deny it. 
You keep the permissions on Q in place and mimik them in your web application.

Comment: @Marco I know the task looks ugly :) Or the way we want it to work... But that's the only way we have right now. Thanks for the suggestion, this might work. Not sure how much our IT will be happy over it, but worth discussing...